# How to get 5 day weather forecast using React Hooks and OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, state, openweathermap

So I want to be able to show the 5 day weather forecast for a chosen city, using the OpenWeatherMap API and React.

I've seen a few tutorials online but they all use Class components, I want to use mine using a functional Component and the UseState hook.

I have this working code which allows me to get the CURRENT weather,location name and displays a little weather icon.

I want to be able to get the info for 5 days, and put it into a list. Specificially I want the high, low, main, description and an icon, for each day.

I'm really inexperienced at making API calls so I'm struggling to figure it out. I have my API key, and I think my API call should look something like this

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${placename},IE&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`

where placename is a prop I pass to it, and IE is my country code.

I was looking at this tutorial which does what I want, but it uses class-based components instead. I can't figure out how to do it without using classes.

https://medium.com/@leizl.samano/how-to-make-a-weather-app-using-react-403c88252deb

If someone could show me how to do this, that would be much appreciated. Here is my current code that gets just the current temperature.

````
export default function Weather (props) {



// State
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
const [state, setState] = useState('Belfast');


var placename = props.placeprop 


// API KEY AND URL
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${placename},IE&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;



useEffect(() => {
  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => 
        setApiData(data),);
    
}, [apiUrl]);




return (





<div className="weather">
      

      <div>
        {apiData.main ? (
          <div>
            <img
              src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${apiData.weather[0].icon}.png`}
              alt="weather status icon"
            />

               <br/>
              {apiData.name}
              <br/>
              {apiData.main.temp}&deg; C
          </div>

        )

         : (
          <h1>Loading</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
    


    )


} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but I came across this question so I'm sharing what I have.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import css from './Weather.module.css';

function useOpenWeather ({apiKey, lat, lon, units = 'metric'}) {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);

  const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${units}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
          setApiData(data);
      });
  }, [apiUrl]);

  return apiData;
}

function Weather ({lat, lon}) {
  const weather = useOpenWeather({
    apiKey: API_KEY
    lat,
    lon,
    units: 'imperial'
  });

  return (
    <div className={css.weather}>
      {weather && weather.daily.slice(0, 5).map(d => (
        <div>
          <img
            src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${d.weather[0].icon}.png`}
            alt={d.weather[0].main}
          />
          <div>{d.temp.max} / {d.temp.min}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Weather;
```

```css
.weather {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 16px;
  margin: 16px;
}
```